# Where can I get a Xerces-C compatible with XML::XERCES 2.7.0?

Tags: perl, installation, cpan

This question is in continuation of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1581212/update-errors-installing-xmlxercers-module-from-cpan), I have tried installing Xerces-C but the thing is Xerces-C version is 2.8.0 and 3.0.0 and XML::XERCES latest version is 2.7.0 and so am getting following error message:

**Update2:** Here is the error which am getting, it says there is somekind of version mismatch.

```
Using XERCES_LIB = /home/adoshi/XML-Parser/Parser2/
xerces-c_2_8_0-hppa-hpux-acc_3(1)/xerces-c_2_8_0-hppa-hpux-acc_3/lib
Using XERCES_INCLUDE = /home/adoshi/XML-Parser/Parser2/
xerces-c_2_8_0-hppa-hpux-acc_3(1)/xerces-c_2_8_0-hppa-hpux-acc_3/include

WARNING

You have defined the XERCESCROOT variable, but the file:

      XERCESCROOT/src/xercesc/config.status

 does not seem to point to the config.status file that was used to
 build your Xerces-C library. Without that file, I may not be able to
 properly build the C++ glue files that come with Xerces.pm.


Proceeding anyway ...
Using Xerces-C version info from /home/adoshi/XML-Parser/Parser2/xerces
-c_2_8_0-hppa-hpux-acc_3(1)/xerces-c_2_8_0-hppa-hpux-acc_3/include/xercesc/util
/XercesVersion.hpp
      *** Version Mismatch ***

You are attempt to build XML::Xerces-2.7.0-0 using Xerces-C-2.8.0,
this will most likely fail, so I am aborting.

You must use Xerces-C-2.7.0
```

Any guidance would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I guess XML::XERCES version out is 2.7.0 and Xerces-C versions out are 2.8.0 and 3.0.0, so what are the possible ways to get XML::XERCES Parser up and running ?

Comment: This could have been dealt with on the original question...

Comment: Yep - you need to match versions between XML::XERCES and the library

Comment: The error message seems to tell you exactly what to do. It's quite a nice message at that. I wish all software were as helpful when they failed. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you read the [download page](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/download.cgi) that clearly says "Older releases are available from [the archive download site](http://archive.apache.org/dist/xml/xerces-c/)."? Perhaps you can find a 2.7.0 release there.

Comment: Got it !!! Thanks !!! Need to get my eye sight checked :) and learn to concentrate more...