# Install/use perl-XML-Xerces-2.7.0 with Xercec-C 3.1.3 on RedHat 7.2

Tags: xml, perl, installation, redhat, xerces

Referring to the similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589560/where-can-i-get-a-xerces-c-compatible-with-xmlxerces-2-7-0), I see what Mark Aufflick answered, but I still think the situation is not clear here. Is there a way to install/use perl-XML-Xerces-2.7.0 with Xercec-C 3.1.3 on RedHat 7.2?

I quickly found first rpm: perl-XML-Xerces-2.7.0_0-4.el5.x86_64.rpm

```
$ rpm -i perl-XML-Xerces-2.7.0_0-4.el5.x86_64.rpm
 warning: perl-XML-Xerces-2.7.0_0-4.el5.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 DSA/SHA1 Signature

 error: Failed dependencies:
 libxerces-c.so.27()(64bit) is needed by perl-XML-Xerces-2.7.0_0-4.el5.x86_64

 perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.8.8) is needed by perl-XML-Xerces-2.7.0_0-4.el5.x86_64
```

Obviously I got an error, this is clear. **I have many questions now:**

1. What is the point to release newer version of xerces-c if perl-XML-Xerces 2.7.0 still works only with older version?
2. The latest perl-XML-xerces is always available in source format, that automatically makes me to build it using the same version of xerces-c. I don't want/don't have/not allowed to build anything and need only Xerces.pm and Xerces.so files compatible with xerces-c-3.1.1, where/how can I get ones?
3. Error below makes me thinking that I need Perl 5.8.8. Come on, RedHat 7.2 (3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64) comes by default with Perl 5.16.3! And again I want to use perl-XML-Xerces with the latest Perl, but I'm asked to use the older Perl version...

   perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.8.8) is needed by perl-XML-Xerces-2.7.0_0-4.el5.x86_64

**So in short, how to use perl-XML-Xerces-2.7.0 on RedHat7.2 with Perl 5.16 and xerces-c 3.1.3?**

or

**Where do I get compatible binaries of perl-XML-Xerces?**

Comment: Xerces is not binary-compatible even between dot-dot releases. I recommend switch to the libxml2 - `XML::LibXML`: it is tad slower, but requires much less involvement. I have used Xerces in C++ and Perl, and the problems due to version incompatibilities were often and nasty. Unless ultimate performance isn't a goal, switch to `libxml2`.

Comment: It took me a while to try LibXML, looks ok and I would go with this... Unfortunately current project is too big and to replace Xerces with libXML is no go. Thank you fellow.